# PHP validate date in a specific format

Tags: php

I have a birthday in a format mm/dd/yyyy and I want to validate it, I found a link on stackoverflow but couldn't implement it. How would I go about this?

Comment: Just use Date Picker and avoid such stuff. It's not possible to validate a specific date format all the times. 02/03/2012 would be read as 2nd March 2012 as well as 3rd feb 2012. How would you validate it?

Comment: Maybe you could tell us what you tried and the reason why you couldn't implement it?

Comment: I do have a jQuery datepicker, I am trying to validate it in php

Comment: @Lion Right, just avoid server-side validation. That sounds like a solid idea...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse the date for month date and year and then you can use the PHP function checkdate() which you can read about here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php

Other ways would be to use regular expression to check the date and I think there are comments that discuss this on that page as well :)